# Enter words to create a sentence

Tags: batch-file

I am making a bat file to either choose between DHCP or Static address of my computer. The code works fine. What I would like to do now is when the bat file is opened, if the static is chosen, to ask what will be the IP address and the subnet mask. When the addresses are entered, execute the netsh command.

Something like storing the words to create a sentence with the words entered by the user

Something like:

```
echo Enter the IP Address = [IP Address]
echo Enter the Sub Mask = [Subnet Mask]

if [IP Address] == Entered goto Mask

:Mask
if [Subnet Mask] == Entered goto 

:Stat
netsh interface ip set address name="wifi" static [IP Address] [Subnet Mask]
```

Here is the code:

```
@echo off
title IP
echo press 1 to Use DHCP
echo press 2 to Use Static
set /p car=
if %car% == 1 goto DHCP
if %car% == 2 goto Stat
:DHCP
netsh interface ip set address name="wifi" DHCP
pause
exit
:Stat
netsh interface ip set address name="wifi" static 10.14.90.150 255.255.0.0
pause
exit
```

I am new to batch Scripting.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You already have an example in your code on how to get user input.  What is stopping you from creating two more questions to ask for user input?

Comment: What's stopping them @Squashman, is that they are using a batch file and have no idea what it is supposed to do on a line by line basis especially because the user input is blank. roibex, try `SET /?` for an explanation of the `/P` option.

Comment: Thank you guys, it's working. :D                                                                                                      


name="wifi" static %IP% %MASK%